# I have "NA" in a column (meaning North America) that shows blank after CSV is read by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file with a `Country` column containing country codes. In this, "NA" means North America. I need to convert it to UTF-8 format. When using the code below the rows with "NA" show as blank in the exported file:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding='UTF-8')
df.to_csv(r'path+filename',header=None ,encoding = 'UTF-8', index = False)
```

For example,

Input file:

```
Week Country PL Sales$
W01   AE     0I  250
W02   NA     0I  130
```

Output file:

```
Week Country PL Sales$
W01   AE     0I  250
W02          0I  130
```

I have tried to fill other columns in the source file with "NA" that are also  now blank.

Answer (score 4):

`'NA'` is among the default `NaN` values in `na_values`. You need to instruct pandas to exclude the default values when reading in the csv file using [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **keep_default_na: bool, default True**
>
> Whether or not to include the default `NaN` values when parsing the data. Depending on whether
> `na_values` is passed in, the behavior is as follows:
>
> If `keep_default_na` is `True`, and `na_values` are specified, `na_values` is
> appended to the default `NaN` values used for parsing.
>
> If `keep_default_na` is `True`, and `na_values` are not specified, only the
> default `NaN` values are used for parsing.
>
> If `keep_default_na` is `False`, and `na_values` are specified, only the `NaN`
> values specified `na_values` are used for parsing.
>
> If `keep_default_na` is `False`, and `na_values` are not specified, no
> strings will be parsed as `NaN`.
>
> Note that if `na_filter` is passed in as `False`, the `keep_default_na` and
> `na_values` parameters will be ignored.

---

This should do the trick:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding='UTF-8', keep_default_na=False)
```

And depending on what other operations you want to perform, you might also need to define `na_values` accordingly.